# Overriding Pathologic when it comes to img src

Tags: input-formats

I have Pathologic installed and it is working great from normal links in a document, but for anything that points to the file system ( img src for example) I can't get it to not use ?q= in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternatively use the [scanner](http://drupal.org/project/scanner) module or export the DB and use a text editor to replace the domains. Therefore getting rid of pathologic.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to write a custom module, you can implement hook_pathologic_alter() and tell Pathologic to not modify certain paths. See [pathologic.api.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/pathologic.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/pathologic.api.php) for examples.